# Long-lived ConnectionMultiplexer Logging

Tags: c#, memorystream, stackexchange.redis

I have a monitoring service that I'm writing for Redis with `StackExchange.Redis` and am subscribing to certain events. The problem I'm facing is with logging. It takes a `TextWriter`. I would ideally like to shunt this off to an `EventLog` so I use a `MemoryStream` backed `StreamWriter` and dump to the `EventLog` with a `StreamReader` on a Task-based timer.

The issue with this implementation is that in my testing the `MemoryStream` leaks badly even though I use `MemoryStream.SetLength(int)` to clear after each read. The `ConnectionMultipler.Connect()` method only takes a single object and I'm unable to see how to replace that object which means I would I have to renew the `ConnectionMultiplexer` periodically as well.

Does this sound off? Am I missing something? The simpler approach seems to curate a single object but I'm not seeing how to keep that under control. Here is a sample console app to demonstrate.

```
class Program
{
    private static MemoryStream _loggingStream;
    private static StreamReader _reader;

    private static object _padlock = new object();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _loggingStream = new MemoryStream();
        _reader = new StreamReader(_loggingStream);

        var logWriter = new StreamWriter(_loggingStream);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async state => await WriteLog());

        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_padlock);

            try
            {
                await logWriter.WriteLineAsync("hello world " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                await logWriter.FlushAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_padlock);
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task WriteLog()
    {
        while (_loggingStream.Length == 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5));
        }

        string log;

        lock (_padlock)
        {
            _loggingStream.Position = 0;

            log = _reader.ReadToEnd();
            _reader.DiscardBufferedData();
            _loggingStream.SetLength(0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(log);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async state => await WriteLog());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're logging across async calls - there's no guarantee that your lock gets released on the thread where it was locked. Your `Monitor` is unsafe and is probably a source of many issues. I guess you ignored the compiler warning (error?) that you cannot use `lock` around async calls and went for Monitor to circumvent it.

Comment: You could try using `SemaphoreSlim` in this scenario.

Comment: @xxbbcc correct. I've always thought there was something about how the compiler treated `lock` that made it a pain to work with async/await, not that `Monitor` was bad.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I've refactored to use `SemaphoreSlim` but that doesn't solve my actual issue, unfortunately. Still, if it's more thread-safe, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bigsby `lock` gets compiled to `Monitor` - they're one and the same. Most of your issues come from that lock being used on the wrong threads as tasks complete. You'll need to change that part around - `SemaphoreSlim` is a good alternative but try to see if you can do this without locking. (May not be possible.)

Comment: @Bigsby I'd suggest first fixing your code and then updating your question because it's hard to answer it now - I'm not sure what your _actual_ question is. :)

Comment: @xxbbcc I've stated my issue plainly in the second paragraph: "The issue with this implementation is that in my testing the `MemoryStream` leaks badly even though I use `MemoryStream.SetLength(int)` to clear after each read." I'm not asking for on overall code review even though I appreciate heads-up on thread safety.

Comment: @Bigsby `MemoryStream` does not leak badly (or at all). You're doing something wrong and the locking in your question could easily be the problem. It's impossible to answer your question as it is.

Comment: @xxbbcc I've had a lockless implementation and it has the same issue. You're focused on a red-herring. Perhaps that's my bad for adding it in my example. I was trying to be complete.

Comment: @xxbbcc Also, it does leak. Run the code. Memory usage skyrockets. Do a snapshot as it grows. The only object in the diff that is significantly contributing to growth is `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @Bigsby The code in your question has multiple major bugs - there's no value in examining it further. MemoryStream does not leak - it's being used all over the world by thousands of applications that handle hundreds of millions of requests each day. If there was even a hint of a leak in that code, it'd come out in seconds. You need to rewrite your code to correctly handle the stream.

Comment: @xxbbcc "You need to rewrite your code to correctly handle the stream." ... that's why I'm here. This is ultimate a Q&A site. Either help me in this regard or kindly go away.

Comment: @Bigsby You're missing the point. :) I (or anyone else) cannot help you as it is - I said above that I don't even know what your question is. MemoryStream doesn't leak, that cannot be your question. The rest of the code in the question is bad, it cannot be used as a basis for help - you need to start over, get it to a point where the bugs are fixed and then - if it's still not working - post a new question. You have to be willing to accept help if you want people to help you.

Comment: @xxbbcc It is entirely unhelpful to say "your code is too bad, go fix it and come back." Then I wouldn't need to be here. I would love to accept help and switched over to use `SemaphoreSlim` immediately. Everything else since then has been a huge distraction. If you have nothing else to contribute, I'm done talking with you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Memory Stream. The problem is the `Console.WriteLine`. It is *much much* faster to write/read stuff to/from a `MemoryStream` than it is to write to the console in e.g. a typical Windows configuration. You may be zeroing the memory stream every time you read it, but once you have cleared it, you relinquish the lock, and the log-writer starts spinning *very quickly*.

In the first iteration, suppose the log-writing thread has 5ms to write some logs. It will take *more* than 5ms to write that to the console, so by the time the console-writing thread has gone around once, it has *more* than 5ms worth of logs, which will take longer than it took to write the first 5ms worth of logs... so every time the console-writing thread completes writing out the previous state of the logs, it finds it has *even more*, and it takes *even longer* to write it out: yes, the memory stream was consuming all the memory, but that's because it needed the memory to store all the logs while the console-writing thread was busy consuming the last load.

Here is some maths, just for the fun of it:

```
d is rate at which logs are produced
c is how long it takes to consume a unit of logs
x(i) is the volume of logs produced during iteration i of the log-consumer
y(i) is how long it takes to consume the logs produced in iteration i
```

We can write some nice simple equations:

```
y(i) = c*x(i)     (time to consume logs is a linear function of volume)
x(i+1) = d*y(i)   (volume is a linear function of time between iterations)
```

Duly, we can determine how the volume of logs (proportional to memory usage) changes with each iteration

```
x(i+1) = d*c*x(i)
```

If `d*c > 1`, then `x` grows exponentially: bad for memory usage (though it can still only grow linearly in time, because `d` is the limiting factor (recall we are looking at costs per iteration, not time))

If we consider `1/c` (the rate at which logs are consumed), then it's clear that this condition is met when

```
d > 1/c (i.e. rate at which logs are produced is greater than the rate at which logs are consumed)
```

Writing to a memory stream is cheaper than writing to the console: `d > 1/c`, so we have a fundamental problem, which no amount of cleverness will solve: you *can't* write such a volume of logs to the console.

You can *see* this problem with the output, because the time-stamp doesn't keep track with clock-time: it falls behind immediately. Removing the `Console.WriteLine` leaves the application settled around 10MB on my machine. You can also see the problem in the memory usage: now and then it jumps, which is the (infrequent) event of the console-writer starting a new iteration, and copying the whole stream (`byte[]`) into a `char[]` (`ReadToEnd`) and finally producing a `string`: it doesn't matter than the `byte[]` can be immediately freed, because you have 2 objects the same size to take up the slack.

---

Incidentally, using `SetLength(0)` will only have obscured the issue by creating more byte-arrays, and may have actually increased the peak memory usage, because it doesn't reduce the max-capacity of the memory stream and means there are discarded objects lying around waiting to be garbage collected.

---

As has been discussed in the comments, you should not be accessing a monitor between threads; your use of `await` means the context will be preserved when control is returned to the log-writing method, but there is no guarantee you'll get the same thread.

Comment: I completely didn't think of this. I did try to set some wait timings as I was curious if it was a drain rate issue but I still saw a climb albeit more slowly. Though, if `Console.WriteLine` is the problem that would still make sense why there was an increase over time.

Comment: @Bigsby if you comment out the `Console.WriteLine` does it still climb in memory usage into the giga-bytes? If so, there is something more at play, but on my machine (Win 7, Framework 4.7) it is definitely this. (It would help a lot of you presented your evidence as to why you suspect the memory stream; I did this investigation from the ground up, testing various things before it hit me that the `Console.WriteLine` was outside the `lock`. As was stated earlier in the comments, suggesting there is a leak is not enough to go on: people mistake normal GC behaviour for leaks all the time)

Comment: On Win 10, 4.7.2 I hover around 25 MB but I do hover. So yes that was my "leak" issue. The reason I thought it was a leak or some intrinsic about `MemoryStream` was the memory snapshotting tool. Typically when you have an isolated delta that keeps going up and on its own accounts for 99+% memory usage, that's memory that isn't getting released properly, hence a leak. This isn't a leak and is more a resource utilization race-case between the tortoise and hare. I had diagnosed this slightly as I mentioned but didn't test the `Console.WriteLine` as it's never been a problem for me.

Comment: @Bigsby I must apologise, I _completely_ misread your previous comment. Glad you got it sorted.